# How to post with a submit form an arraylist of a children object?

Tags: html, spring, forms, thymeleaf

I'm trying to post a form and see what happens when there are errors in some fields.

I use Thymeleaf to get the object and put it in inputs that are posted in the form.

When I have an error in the fields (BindingResults), all the fields are correctly sent besides two of them that are ArrayList < ChildrenObject >

```
<input id="roles" name="roles" th:value="${user.roles}"/>
```

In my post method, the dto (User) contains all the fields, but not the roles.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "/users/{id}")
String editUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") UserRestDto dto, BindingResult errors, @RequestParam String id) {
```

After posting, all the values are set, I see the errors, but not these two fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define `modelAttribute="user"`  in your form:

```
<form:form action="/someaction" method="POST"  modelAttribute="user">
```

for example if you have form like this:

```
<form:form action="/someaction" method="POST"  modelAttribute="user">
  ...
 <form:select path="users" items="${users}" multiple="true" />
  ...
</form>
```

your Spring mvc code should be like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someaction", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView someaction(@ModelAttribute(value = "user") UserRestDto user) {
```

Comment: did you tried:   form:input with "path" parameter for data binding